# How to ommit fromJS/toJSON in Swagger client generation?

Tags: typescript, swagger, swagger-codegen

Is there any parameter that prevent generating fromJS/toJSON while generating client code for Angular?

Comment: could you please brief what is the problem you are facing by having these methods?

Comment: This is not a big problem - I simply want to generate smaller file. For now I have no need for those methods so I have looked for some switch for turning them off.

Comment: You can probably modify the template to avoid generating that bit. I couldn't found where it is generated in typescript-angular2 but if you include an example of what it is getting generated now and what version of angular I can help you find which template to modify.